# Print out list of Imagecache presets

Tags: 6, forms, media

I just need an array of the preset names, is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[imagecache_presets](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!imagecache!imagecache.module/function/imagecache_presets/6)

Get an array of all presets and their settings.

Parameters

reset: if set to TRUE it will clear the preset cache

Return value

array of presets `array( $preset_id => array('presetid' => integer, 'presetname' => string))`

Comment: This causes a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ..."

Comment: huh? Cross check the spelling. Works for me. Its imagecache_presets() and NOT imagecache_preset()

Comment: Also obviously make sure imagecache module is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :)